# Date is outputted wrong

Tags: c#

On the code below the value dt outputted should be 2018/05/30 but it is 30/01/2018.
Why ?

```
string dateString = “2018/05/30”;

// Convert to correct format and make sure it is a valid format
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "yyyy/mm/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
// Do something important
}
```

Comment: A `DateTime` doesn't hold formatting...

Comment: There is no output happening in that code.

Comment: Missing an important part here. Where is the output?

Comment: You are specifying minutes instead of months in your format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Date format is `yyyy/MM/dd` and not `yyyy/mm/dd`

`mm` is used for `minutes` from `0-59` and `MM` is used for `month`

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "yyyy/MM/dd",    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
// Do something important
}
```